# PostgreSQL difference between VACUUM FULL and CLUSTER

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, clustered-index, vacuum

I have a table with 200 GB of size occupied by data and 180 GB of size by the 6 indexes on it. It is 30% bloated, so I want to reclaim unwanted space occupied by it. It is clustered on `job_id_id`x index.

So to reclaim the space do I need to use `cluster` command or `vacuum full` command?

1. What is the difference between this two command ?
2. Is `vacuum full` order by some column same as `cluster` command?
3. Is index recreated in both the commands?
4. In my case which one will be faster?

The version of PostgreSQL database is 9.1

Comment: Yes, the indexes will be recreated.  Which is faster depends on a few things, I imagine.  But one thing is sure: there is nothing like 'vacuum full order by some column'.

Comment: Let me also mention that VACUUM can't run inside a transaction which in many cases makes CLUSTER a better alternative (and sometimes the only alternative) that produces similar results.

Answer (score 13):

To check what `CLUSTER` does, I took a table fo mine from an earlier experiment which basically contained the first 10 million positive integers.  I already deleted some rows and there is an other column as well but these only affect the actual table size, so it is not that interesting.

First, having run `VACUUM FULL` on the table `fka`, I took its size:

```
\dt+ fka
                    List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner   |  Size  | Description 
--------+------+-------+----------+--------+-------------
 public | fka  | table | test     | 338 MB |
```

Then let's see the physical order of the data from the very beginning of the table:

```
SELECT *, ctid FROM fka ORDER BY ctid LIMIT 5;

 id  | col1 |  ctid   
-----+------+---------
   2 | 2    | (0,1)
   3 | 3    | (0,2)
   4 | 4    | (0,3)
   5 | 5    | (0,4)
   6 | 6    | (0,5)
```

Now let's delete some rows:

```
DELETE FROM fka WHERE id % 10 = 5;
--DELETE 1000000
```

After this, the reported table size did not change.  So let's see now what `CLUSTER` does:

```
CLUSTER fka USING fka_pkey;

SELECT *, ctid FROM fka ORDER BY ctid LIMIT 5;

 id  | col1 |  ctid   
-----+------+---------
   2 | 2    | (0,1)
   3 | 3    | (0,2)
   4 | 4    | (0,3)
   6 | 6    | (0,4)
   7 | 7    | (0,5)
```

After the operation the table size changed from 338 to 296 MB.  From the `ctid` column, which describes the physical place of the tuple in the page, you also see that there is no gap where the row matching `id = 5` used to be.

As the tuples were reordered, indexes should have been recreated so that they point to the correct places.

So the difference looks to be that `VACUUM FULL` does not order the rows.  As far as I know, there is some difference in the mechanism the two commands use but from a practical point of view this seems to be the main (only?) difference.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the `ctid` column is. Turns out it is a system column describing the physical location of the row within its table. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html

Answer (score 10):

> `VACUUM FULL` rewrites the entire contents of the table into a new
>   disk file with no extra space, allowing unused space to be returned to
>   the operating system. This method also requires extra disk space,
>   since it writes a new copy of the table and doesn't release the old
>   copy until the operation is complete. Usually this should only be used
>   when a significant amount of space needs to be reclaimed from within
>   the table.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html

> `CLUSTER` instructs PostgreSQL to cluster the table specified by
>   table_name based on the index specified by index_name. The index must
>   already have been defined on table_name. When a table is clustered, it
>   is physically reordered based on the index information and an ACCESS
>   EXCLUSIVE lock is acquired on it.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html

also intresting: [is-a-reindex-required-after-cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39652/is-a-reindex-required-after-cluster)

But maybe all you need is a simple `REINDEX` which rebuilds an index using the data stored in the index's table, replacing the old copy of the index.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-reindex.html